# Large number of sqlite databases in the same application

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite

I am creating a web application whose purpose is to allow many users with a very specific activity, to manage their daily work on that platform. Basically there is no sharing of information between users. I am developing in Laravel / PHP.

I would like to know, from your experience, if you think there is any inconvenience in having a central database of users and then each of them can have their own small SQLite databases. We are talking about the possibility that each user can create 5 or 6 SQLite databases. If the platform has 5000 users, we will be talking about 25000 small SQLite databases (300kb max size).

I know this idea may seem silly, but it is the one that makes sense in my project for various reasons.

In your experience, do you think that such a large number of databases can be a problem?

Comment: It might make your server's disk very very busy... Maybe this should actually be some sort of properly designed cloud SAAS platform, if you're anticipating that volume of users?

Comment: I hope so, but it will not be a very busy platform. It is a remake of a desktop app that I've created 10 years ago, and I know that most of the users only spend 10 minutes a day there.

Comment: You are going to miss out on things like having a DB in a separate instance. Using a DB cluster rather than single instance etc etc.

Comment: Why not just set up a database server (mysql, mariadb, postgres or similar) and let the users share the same database? I don't see what the gain is from having 25000 sqlite databases lying around in the filesystem?